# Expo Speech does not work on iOS - React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

SDK Version: 49
Platform: iOS
Question: expo-speech does not work on iOS but works on android very well. Also i tested my app in iOS 17.0 and 16.4. it does not work on both. My code is here. Some one can help me?

```
await Speech.speak(text, { 
    onDone: () => { 
        setIsPlaying(false); 
    } 
});
```

What is the problem? I need to learn how to fix this.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? If you get an error, please post the error message, or clarify what happens and what you've tried.

Comment: OnDone callback doesn't call on Ios facing same issue

Comment: I have upgraded my expo-speech version to"^11.5.0  and now callback works

Comment: some functions are platform-specific check the source code of expo speech https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/main/packages/expo-speech/ios/SpeechModule.swift

Answer (score 0):

if OnDone callback is not working on ios then try to upgrade your expo-speech version working fine on ^11.5.0 I also has the issue with onDone callback but after upgrading it works